# How do I project-range in a nested tuple via dereferencing using Apache Pig?

Tags: syntax, apache-pig

I have tuple like so:

```
(a: (b:int, c:int, d:int, e:int))
```

I would like to call a UDF and pass a range of the nested tuple.  This is what I would expect the command to be:

```
FOREACH alias GENERATE myUDF(a.(c .. e));
```

but this gives me an error like

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 12, column 133>  mismatched input '(' expecting SEMI_COLON
```

What is the proper way to perform this operation?

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: What kind of input does your UDF expect?  A tuple, or a series of elements?  The input to every UDF is encapsulated in a tuple, so will this tuple have one element (which is itself a tuple), or will it have many elements (3 in your example)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  If your tuple is not too long, it hopefully won't be too cumbersome to use the `TOTUPLE` built-in UDF and list each member individually:

```
FOREACH alias GENERATE myUDF(TOTUPLE(a.c, a.d, a.e));
```

But you are probably asking this question because it will be cumbersome for your application.  In that case you could start by `FLATTEN`ing the tuple and then doing a range:

```
FOREACH (FOREACH alias GENERATE FLATTEN(a)) GENERATE myUDF(TOTUPLE(a::c .. a::e));
```

I'm not sure exactly what you expect to be passing to the UDF --  a smaller tuple?  Or a collection of elements from the original tuple?  Depending on what your UDF does, the above `TOTUPLE`s may be superfluous.